# Using array to define class in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to use a function to alter the css of many html elements. I was wondering how I could make this work.

```
var i = 0 var playerimg=["CSGO_de_cache.jpg"];

var playerdefine=["#p1"];



for(i = 0; i<15; i++) { 
    $(playerdefine[0]).prepend("<img class=\"playerimg\" src=\"Pictures/" + playerimg[playercounter] + "\">" ) 
}
```

The "playerdefine" is the one I am insecure about since it doesnt work atm, should it work or are there any other ways I could define differnt tags?

This is my first post and I am not used to all the programming lingo(all the less in English) so be free to correct me.

Thanks for taking ur time!

Comment: It should be like `playerdefine=["#p1"]`

Comment: The `playerdefine` variable seems pretty redundant (even after correcting the syntax). What is the contents of the `playerimg` array? Could you post a more complete sample of your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  var i = 0
    var playerimg=["CSGO_de_cache.jpg"];
    var playerdefine=["#p1"];

for(i = 0; i<15; i++){   
$(playerdefine[0]).prepend("<img class=\"playerimg\" src=\"Pictures/" + playerimg[playercounter] + "\">" )

    
} Thats all there is to it, atleast this part, there are 400 lines of codes but thats insignifigant to this part

Comment: @Noxcre please use the `edit` button on the question, and take care to format it so it's readable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It is not editable anymore and I tried from the start and it didnt display the breakers. Ill write it in answers EDIT: Rewrote in the question

Answer (score 0):

do something like below assuming playerimg and playercounter is defined or replace playercount with i

```
var i = 0   
var playerdefine=["#p1"];
for(i = 0; i<playerdefine.length; i++){   
    $(playerdefine[i]).prepend('<img class="playerimg" src="Pictures/' + playerimg[i] +'">' );
}
```

Comment: Yes, thats the plan, the problem is that "playerdefine" doesnt seem to work while trying to reach #p1, when I write "$("#p1") it works.

Comment: yes because playerdefine has only 1 element and loop is running 15 times. i am updating answer

Comment: are you getting any error in console if so paste it here in comment. also playerimg variable has valid array or not?

Comment: Thanks, player img was the problem, not the part with the array but with the player counter, I had not defined it thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Like I see in your question is about adding images to players list elements.
Fallowing code may help you ;)

```
// players list
// 1) use nested objects is more simple
// 2) with objects you never break things
//    like player1 with image of player 4
// 3) learn jquery and javascript basics there are many videos on youtube


var playersList = [
    {
        id: '#p1',
        img: 'image1.jpg',
    },
    {
        id: '#p2',
        img: 'image2.jpg',
    },
     //......
    {
        id: '#pN',
        img: 'imageN.jpg',
    }
];

var imgDir = 'images/players/';

// adding images to elements wich id's in players list array
// playersList.length ??? - how many elements do we have

for(var i = 0, i < playersList.length, i++){
    $(playersList[i].id).prepend( $('<img src="'+imgDir+playersList[i].img+'" alt="player-img" />').addClass('playerimg') );
}
```

Note need to put this code after doom loads in order to access elements.